# jQuery Datatables: Pass returned JSON to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am using 2 plugins ...

- [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) (To provide pagination)
- [Defiant.js](http://defiantjs.com/) (To provide JSON search capability)

Here is my problem and code ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myjson;

//Initialize Datatable
    var newtable = $('#pdf-results').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://www.example.com/home/Dummy_JSON_data.js",
            "dataSrc": function(json) {
             myjson: json; // This is the problem. I am not sure how to assign returned JSON to a variable ?
            }
        }
    });

// On button click, pass the returned JSON results to Defiant code below for searching and redraw Datatable.

    $("button").click(function() {
        var cname = $("#name").val();
        console.log('cname', cname);
        var cyear = $("#year").val();

        var rawXPath_cName = '//*[(contains(courseName, "' + cname + '") or contains(courseCode, "' + cname + '")) and contains(Year, "' + cyear + '")]';
        //console.log(rawXPath_cName);
        try {
            var reds = JSON.search(myjson, rawXPath_cName);
            var table_body = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
                table_body += '<tr>';
                table_body += '<td>' + reds[i].courseCode + '</td>';
                table_body += '<td>' + reds[i].courseName + '</td>';
                table_body += '<td>' + reds[i].Year + '</td>';
                table_body += '<td>' + reds[i].Trimester + '</td>';
                table_body += '<td><a href = ' + reds[i].pdfURL + '>Download map</a></td>';
                table_body += '</tr>';
            }
            $("tbody").empty();
            $("tbody").append(table_body);
            newtable.ajax.reload(); // Also, not sure if this is required or not. 
            //When the table redraws based on user search query, datatables doesn't display pagination correctly. It sometimes it shows 4-5 rows on page 1 and 4-5 rows on page 2, instead of showing upto 10 rows on page 1, which is the default behavior.

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('No results found');
        }
    });
});
```

I need to assign the data returned by Ajax call to a variable, so that I can use those results in the defiant.js code to search the result set. Essentially this code **myjson: json;** above is failing.

Comment: Create a public global variable then when "data" comes back from the ajax you can just pass it tot he global variable, run your functions against it and then output. I'll post an example in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I'm reading the API correctly, but it looks like you want to use ajax.json() - https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json()

```
var newtable = $('#pdf-results').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://www.example.com/home/Dummy_JSON_data.js"
    }
});

//new code
newtable.on('xhr', function(){
    var json = newtable.ajax.json();
    myjson = json.data; //bind to global variable
    alert(json.data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @googabeast json.data returns _undefined_ Also, I just want to use Datatables with rows being returned via an AJAX call. https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html But, What's complicating the situation is that there is another plugin/library Defiant.js which need to use the the JSON data.

Comment: what does the following snippit return?   console.log($('#pdf-results').data("DataTable")); It seems to me that in all plugins the API contains all returned results sets as well as the basic config. If you use FireFox try   copy($('#pdf-results').data("DataTable")) and paste the results here.

Comment: In both Firefox and Chrome, this `console.log($('#pdf-results').data("DataTable"));` is returning _undefined_. Also I have found something that may help https://datatables.net/examples/api/api_in_init.html but not sure how to implement this in my case ....

Answer (score -1):

According to [the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc), it should work simply by declaring a global variable (`myjson` in this case), and assign the JSON data to it in the `dataSrc` function:

```
var newtable = $('#pdf-results').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://www.example.com/home/Dummy_JSON_data.js",
            "dataSrc": function(json) {
                 myjson = json; // '=', not ':'
                 return json;
            }
        }
    });
```

In your code you're trying to assign the json to the variable using `:` instead of `=`. Maybe that's why it's failing?

Also, don't forget to return the data in the `dataSrc` function, so DataTables can use it.